# How do data breapoints work?

Tags: debugging, breakpoints

There are a great number of articles describing how breakpoints work, like [this](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/How_Do_Breakpoints_Work) and [this](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/01/23/how-debuggers-work-part-1). However, I could not find any reliable information on how **data** breakpoints work, i.e. breakpoints which are triggered when a particular address in memory is modified. Doesn't seem very difficult after reading these articles, still would like to know exactly how this is done. Thanks.

Comment: That would depend on the architecture (and sometimes the model) of the CPU. Most have some built-in limited number of hardware-supported data breakpoints. For those that don't, software-only implementations are possible but not usually practical due to the performance overhead. Sometimes it is a hybrid: use some hardware features such as memory protection but implement the actual change detection in software.

Comment: Agreed that it depends on the architecture and the debugger.  If you're interested in how in how debuggers generally do this on Intel x86/AMD processors, see the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_debug_register) on x86 debug registers.